# Особенности соблюдения стандарта usb операционными системами и библиотеками

Tags: usb

Проблема: устройство usb (CDC) нормально работает на Windows 7 и не работает на windows 10 (на других не проверял). Устройство построено на микроконтроллере stm32f103. При этом, когда использовалась библиотека SPL, устройство работало нормально, а когда перешёл на CubeMX (фактически - полностью переписал прошивку), стала наблюдаться сия проблема. Выкладывать код в данном случае не вижу возможности, так как его будет тонна.

Симптомы неверной работы устройства таковы. Открытие устройства средствами драйвера libusb происходит успешно, но все последующие пакеты данных (bulk) не отправляются. С отладчиком тоже непонятки: когда запускаю контроллер под отладчиком и взаимодействую с ним из Win7, всё замечательно, устройство открывается, обмен данными идёт. Когда контроллер запущен под отладчиком и взаимодействует с Win10, оно перестаёт открываться, при этом прошивка не попадает в breakpoint функции, которая возвращает дескриптор конфигурации.

В связи с этим вопрос: какие есть особенности соблюдения / не соблюдения стандарта usb операционными системами семейства Windows NT, библиотекой libusb, библиотеками SPL и CubeMX?

Одну из них я могу назвать сам: Windows 7 может продолжить работать с устройством, если в дескрипторе конфигурации указана неверная длина. В Windows 10 в этом случае в диспетчере устройств появляется неизвестное устройство. Но этот косяк я уже устранил. Какие ещё могут быть варианты?

Comment: А попробуйте послушать что по USB ходит, может найдете причину...